# Spaces are not visible in output from database

Tags: php, html, css, whitespace

I stored some data in database in the following format:

```
    XXXXX
      X
    XXXXX
```

The whitespace is significant. When I retrieve the data from the database using PHP and then output it to my HTML page the whitespace is removed.

I'm using [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) to convert the newline characters to `<br>` tags and that works well. Is there something I can use to do the same for spaces?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: when i retrieve data I use only nl2br()

Comment: Please start to read a book about HTML, how it works, how it deals with whitespace etc. That's often one chapter/section in HTML books.

Answer (score 4):

You're outputting to an HTML page which doesn't show consecutive spaces. You can wrap your output in `<pre>` `</pre>` (the pre-formatted tag) to get spaces to show up as they are stored.

Alternatively you can apply the CSS style `white-space: pre` to the HTML element that you are outputting that inside. You can read about the different value for `white-space` [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/white-space).

Note that the default behaviour is `normal` which states:

> This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space

Comment: @kishor You're welcome! Since you've asked `3` questions on Stack Overflow and haven't accepted any answers yet I'm going to point you here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . If you feel an answer has solved your problem it is nice to accept it and award some rep to the user that answered. It also gives you a little bit of rep too.

Comment: @ascii-lime Now that you already brought the topic on good manner and stuff like that, I'd like to point out that you as a 25k member should close questions like this one as "too localized" instead of answering them. Such questions are unlikely to help any future visitor :)

Comment: @NikiC I saw nothing wrong enough with this question to close it, but I have edited it to make it a bit more searchable so maybe it will help some future visitor now.

Comment: @ascii-lime In that case it's still a duplicate though ^^ But anyways, thanks for editing :)